# Modulo Arithmetic equations

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How to find the value of the unknown in the equations . I have tried finding the value y by equating the left hand side to the right hand side
 $\;20\pmod 9 = y\pmod6$, find the value of $y$

Comment: The equation makes no sense as written. Maybe you mean $\,20\bmod 9\,=\, y\bmod 6$ ? Please clarify.  Where does the equation come from?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

First of all, reduce the equation: as $20\equiv 2\mod 9$, the equation is 
$$ˆy\mod 6= 2\mod 9$$
Next, translate what it means in a concrete way: there exist $k,\ell\in \mathbf Z$ such that
$$y+6k=2+9\ell\iff y=2+9\ell-6k.$$
Last: think of Bézout's identity.